# The dynamic routes doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, electron, dynamic-routing

I am using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) for routing. Here is the code inside `routes.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = require('express')

var hosSchemaModel = require('./app/schema.js')
var path    = require("path")


app.get('/requests/:_id', (req, res, next) =>   {
    console.log('Dynamic Link WORKS!!');
    hosSchemaModel.findOne({ _id: req.params._id }, function(err, request){
        res.json(request)
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'../homePage.html'))
    });
});
```

Inside the `homePage.html` I used `<script>` tag to include `routes.js`:

```
<script src="handlebars-v4.0.10.js"></script>
```

And here is the piece of code where I am using the route:

```
<div class="card-action">
    <a href="/requests/{{this._doc._id}}">{{this._doc.status}}</a>
    <a href="#">{{this._doc.createdAt}}</a>
</div>
```

Based on the router implementation, "Dynamic Link WORKS!!" should be printed to the console but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"Inside the homePage.html I used <script> tag to include routes.js:"* does not make any sense at all.  You don't put route handlers in your HTML file.  They belong on the server with your Express server.  You've either written your question wrong or you are way off in how to implement a route in Express.  I'm not sure which because you have elements of both in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It could be many things, but as a natural flow:

- Check if the request is correct: (inspect -> network)
- If it is ok, check its response. From the response you can have a good feeling of what's happening.
- Try a simplier router. Ex: "/all"
- Maybe your handlebars-v4.0.10.js is not being loaded, I would double check its path.

I hope these steps help you find where's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be in the beginning lines of your code only instead of these :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = require('express')
```

Try this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

Comment: I am using ElectronJS so I am using "app = require('electron')

Comment: inside "app.on" I am calling express();